# How to refer to a variable in an outer scope

Tags: scala

If I have the following code:

```
trait MyTrait {
    val x: Int
}

def f(_x: Int) = new MyTrait {
    val x = _x
}
```

If I were to define my function as follows:

```
def f(x: Int) = new MyTrait {
    val x = x
}
```

This would be incorrect as val x is just referring to itself. Is there a way I can avoid having to use a different name for 'x' when I want to refer to something in the outer scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really: in the scope of `MyTrait`, `x` refers to the field. However, you have the option to wrap parameter into some other name before you enter that scope:

```
def f(x: Int) = {
  val xn = x
  new MyTrait {
    val x = xn
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can, but only if the outer scope `x` is a member of enclosing type, not a method parameter or a local variable:

```
class MyOuter(val x: Int) {
  def f() = new MyTrait {
    val x = MyOuter.this.x
}
```

Comment: I would upvote more if I could. I knew it is possible, but struggled to find the proper language spec section: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#designators

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this particular case, you could write something like this:

```
 def f(x: Int) = {
    class Foo(val x: Int = x) extends MyTrait
    new Foo
  }
```

Not sure what exactly it makes better over just renaming `x` to `y` though ...